# How to run Jetty with SPDY using ALPN on NETBEANS?

Tags: java, netbeans, jetty, okhttp, alpn

is there a way to run Jetty with SPDY using ALPN on Netbeans? I'm trying to use but it shows this message on console:

> nov 14, 2015 4:40:01 PM
> com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform
>
> getSelectedProtocol INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are
> disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?

I'm using the JDK 8u66 and the alpn-boot-8.1.6.v20151105.jar on my netbeans project

So when I try to use this command java **-Xbootclasspath/p:** on my CMD, I do like this:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:libs/alpn-boot-8.1.6.v20151105.jar Test
```

But nothing happens, or it can't run the main class and I don't know why.

I take this command from the Jetty website itself:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html

and I'm using this code on Test.class

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        List<Protocol> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
        test.add(Protocol.HTTP_2);
        client.setProtocols(test);

        HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("https://webtide.com/");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.headers());

        
    }
}
```

This code is using the OKhttp technology that supports HTTP/2. The main of this code is to discover if some website uses HTTP/2 or not.

Comment: Try using the fully-qualified path to your ALPN jar?

Comment: Do you mean HTTP/2 and not SPDY? (as SPDY is 100% deprecated in Jetty and all Browsers now)

Comment: Yes, in this case is the HTTP/2, is that possible on Netbeans?